# boost unordered_map serialization says 'serialize' missing even with appropriate includes

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, unordered-map

I've got a simple class with an unordered map and a serialize function:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>

class to_serialize {
  boost::unordered_map<int, int> m_map;
public:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) {
    ar & m_map;
  }
};
```

Now I try to create a ts object and serialize it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include "ts.cpp"

int main() {
  to_serialize ts;
  std::ofstream ofs("saved.bin");
  {
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << ts;
  }
  ofs.close();
}
```

This fails to compile, with:

```
boost/serialization/access.hpp:116:9: error: 'class boost::unordered::unordered_map<int, int>' has no member named 'serialize'
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here? The boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp seems to declare and define the serialize function for the unordered map, but I guess that's not enough?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is simple -- boost implements serialization of the STL unordered_map, but not its own boost::unordered_map version :(.